# amalgamating bash code blocks to give choices

Tags: bash

I have two blocks of bash-code that I want to amalgamate. The first checks to see if you have "get-iplayer/get_iplayer" installed and if not prompts for it to be installed -

```
if [[ -x "/usr/bin/get-iplayer" ]]
then player="/usr/bin/get-iplayer"
elif [[ -x "/usr/bin/get_iplayer" ]]
 then player="/usr/bin/get_iplayer"
elif [[ -x "/usr/local/bin/get_iplayer" ]]
then player="/usr/local/bin/get_iplayer"
else echo "$0: Error: 'get-iplayer' or 'get_iplayer' is not installed. Please install it." >&2
 exit 1
fi
```

I now want to add in the ability to choose which one you use, I actually have all 3 of them installed but want to use the one at /usr/local/bin, like so -

```
{
    read -n1 -p "$(tput setaf 5)
            get-iplayer = a,
            get_iplayer = b,
            new get_iplayer = c,
            quit = q? [a/b/c/q] " abcq
    echo; echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S) Answer: $abcq" >> $log
   case "$abcq" in
        [a]* ) /usr/bin/get-iplayer & echo;;
        [b]* ) /usr/bin/get_iplayer & echo;;
        [c]* ) /usr/local/bin/get_iplayer & echo;;
            [q]* ) echo; exit;;
        * )
     esac
 }
```

But how can I do it please? I've been sitting here trying to puzzle it out, but not getting anywhere.

You must be able to see what you are choosing, which must ultimately be called "player" as that is its variable-name in the rest of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to hold the existing executables, then the little-used `select` command to choose:

```
iplayers=()
for possible in /usr/bin/get-iplayer /usr/bin/get_iplayer /usr/local/bin/get_iplayer; do
    [[ -x $possible ]] && iplayers+=("$possible")
done
if (( ${#iplayers[@]} == 0 )); then
    echo "$0: Error: 'get-iplayer' or 'get_iplayer' is not installed. Please install it." >&2
    exit 1
fi

PS3="Select an iplayer: "
select choice in "${iplayers[@]}"; do
    [[ -n $choice ]] && break
done

echo "you chose: $choice"
```